# Como disminuir en apps script tiempo de ejecución de una función cuando debes llamar continuamente a slidesApp y a SpreadsheetApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, eficiencia

Tengo un mapa mundial creado en Google slides que contiene diferentes territorios y cada territorio tiene un anillo y dentro del mismo un numero. El anillo solo es visible si el texto del numero no esta vacío. Los datos se recogen de una hoja de google independiente en el rango "E3:F26". La idea es que al seleccionar la FUNCIÓN CARGAR se actualicen los colores de cada territorio y el numero de tropas del territorio.

La función que he creado funciona perfectamente pero demora unos 30 segundos o más en terminar y la experiencia de usuario es muy muy lenta.

He añadido un fragmento de código con tan solo 3 territorios de 24 ya que prácticamente el código se repite una y otra vez. Este fragmento tarda 7 segundos en completarse y me gustaría poder disminuir drásticamente este intervalo de tiempo. En cuanto al código, son 3 territorios, los dos primeros son prácticamente iguales pero el tercero cambia ya que hay que sumarle una forma más. La razón por la que estoy usando objectId es porque al ser formas libres extraidas de una svg no las reconoce como objeto si no es mediante las ids.

Lo que me gustaría es saber como puedo hacer mas eficiente este código. He intentado llamar menos veces a slidesApp y a SpreadsheetApp utilizando arrays pero no he conseguido nada, no me arroja error pero tampoco hace nada.  Estaría muy agradecido si alguien consiguiera que este código sea mucho mas rápido. Muchas gracias de antemano!

````
    
const ssurl = "1r9Drd4oxczM6xM8pbhRQCBU3jlD9C9OqjH594ky21rA"; //INSERTAR ID DEL SPREADSHEET "DATOS".
const slideurl = "11d9emgGA-IKM_nJce1wu1xPeLjY4MGpDD4I8MiQMZ-c"; //INSERTAR ID DEL SLIDE "RISK MAPA".

    function cargar() {

        const hexText = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssurl).getSheetByName('RISK COMP')
        .getRange("E3:F26").getValues();
        //Logger.log(hexText[3][0]);
        const slide = SlidesApp.openById(slideurl).getSlides()[0];

      //norteAmerica
        const norteAmericaobjId = ["g11262e0cb1e_0_240","g11262e0cb1e_0_242","g11262e0cb1e_0_243","g11262e0cb1e_0_244","g11262e0cb1e_0_245","g11262e0cb1e_0_246","g11262e0cb1e_0_247","g11262e0cb1e_0_248","g11262e0cb1e_0_249","g11262e0cb1e_0_251","g13282547fe8_0_1"];  
        const norteAmericatextId = "g12fa257bd90_0_175";
        const norteAmericaRingId ="g12fa257bd90_0_176";

        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == norteAmericatextId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getText().setText(hexText[0][1]);
        
        if(hexText[0][1] == ""){
        //Logger.log('hutsa');
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == norteAmericaRingId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill('#ffffff',0);  
        }
        else{
          var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == norteAmericaRingId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill('#ffffff',0.5);  
        }

        norteAmericaobjId.forEach(function(id) {
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == id);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill(hexText[0][0],1);
        
        });

      //esteAsiatico
        const esteAsiaticoobjId = ["g11296648e47_0_30","g11296648e47_0_31","g11296648e47_0_32"];  
        const esteAsiaticotextId = "g12fa257bd90_0_213";
        const esteAsiaticoRingId = "g12fa257bd90_0_214";

        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == esteAsiaticotextId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getText().setText(hexText[14][1]);
        
        if(hexText[14][1] == ""){
        //Logger.log('hutsa');
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == esteAsiaticoRingId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill('#ffffff',0);  
        }
        else{
          var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == esteAsiaticoRingId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill('#ffffff',0.5);  
        }

        esteAsiaticoobjId.forEach(function(id) {
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == id);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill(hexText[14][0],1);
        
        });


      //polinesia
        const polinesiaFormaobjId = ["g12fe47a87ed_1_1","g12fe47a87ed_1_2","g12fe47a87ed_1_3","g12fe47a87ed_1_4","g12fe47a87ed_1_5","g12fe47a87ed_1_6","g12fe47a87ed_1_7","g12fe47a87ed_1_8","g12fe47a87ed_1_9","g12fe47a87ed_1_10","g12fe47a87ed_1_11","g12fe47a87ed_1_15","g12fe47a87ed_1_16","g12fe47a87ed_1_17","g12fe47a87ed_1_18","g12fe47a87ed_1_19","g12fe47a87ed_1_20","g12fe47a87ed_1_21"];  
        const polinesiaFondoobjId = ["g12fa257bd90_0_14","g12fa76b19e0_1_5"]; 
        const polinesiatextId = "g12fa257bd90_0_181";
        const polinesiaRingId = "g12fa257bd90_0_182";

        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == polinesiatextId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getText().setText(hexText[23][1]);
        
        if(hexText[23][1] == ""){
        //Logger.log('hutsa');
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == polinesiaRingId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill('#ffffff',0);  
        }
        else{
          var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == polinesiaRingId);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill('#ffffff',0.5);  
        }

        polinesiaFormaobjId.forEach(function(id) {
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == id);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill(hexText[23][0],1);

        });

        polinesiaFondoobjId.forEach(function(id) {
        var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == id);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getFill().setSolidFill(hexText[23][0],0.5);
        if (obj.length > 0) obj[0].getBorder().getLineFill().setSolidFill(hexText[23][0],1);
        
        });

        }```
````

Comment: Hola Risk Ball, te damos la bienvenida al sitio (no te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre Stack Overflow y ganar una nueva medalla. Esta pregunta ha sido marcada como muy extensa por el sistema. Aunque no requiere acción por tu parte, sería bueno que intentaras reducir el contenido de la pregunta quitando código innecesario para reproducir el problema y quedarte con un [mcve]. De ese modo será más fácil ayudarte. Lee [ask[ para más información. Saludos.

Comment: Editado! Ya he seleccionado una pequeña parte como me has recomendado

Answer (score 0):

El código incluye varias veces `slides.getShapes()`. Declara una variable a la que asignes el resultados de dicha expresión y usa dicha variable en lugar de repetir la expresión tantas veces.

Ejemplo de declaración de variable:

Nota: debes ponerla después de la declaración de `slides` antes de llamarla.

```
const shapes = slides.getShapes();
```

luego, en lugar de un enunciado como el siguiente:

```
var obj = slide.getShapes().filter(s => s.getObjectId() == norteAmericatextId);
```

usa

```
var obj = shapes.filter(s => s.getObjectId() == norteAmericatextId);
```